# How can I make Ctrl + Q add an html in a contenteditable DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this div, by default it accepts ctrl + u to underline for example, but I want to add a custom html to it when ctrl + q is pressed.

```
<div id="dvMy" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [jquery.hotkeys](https://github.com/tzuryby/jquery.hotkeys).

```
jQueryObject.bind('keypress.ctrl_q', functionThatAddsDiv)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this the *old fashioned way* with jQuery hotkeys:

```
$('#dvMy').bind('keypress.ctrl_q', customFxToEditDiv);
```

or if doing more than 1 keyboard shortcut it's really worth it to check out mousetrap.js - it has a really nice DSL for keyboard shortcuts and handles a lot of the details and gotchas that are not so obvious if trying to do it yourself. Also worth it for the awesome url: http://craig.is/killing/mice

```
  Mousetrap.bind('ctrl+q', function(e) {
    $('#dvMy').html('<p>Custom content</p>');
  });
```